# reactjs, get array in state in for loop?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

The Line console.log before if can log a number but the if statement go error with 
    this.state.question[i] is undefined.

after 4 hours I can't understand why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wD9m.png)

Comment: You probably want `< this.state.question.length` instead of `<=`. But why are you setting your state twice, rather than just once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are iterating your `question` array one too many times. If you have 5 items in the array, you want indexes 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. Your loop tries to read index 5 as well because you have: `i <= this.state.question.length`. Try changing this to `i < this.state.question.length` instead.

Also, you are setting your state twice which is unnecessary and may trigger a re-render more than needed. Instead work with a temporary variable:

```js
handlePlay = (e) => {
  setInterval(function(){
    const time = Math.round(e.target.getCurrentTime());
    let obj = {currentTime: time};  //temporary variable to build your next state
    for(let i = 0;i<=this.state.question.length;i++){
      if(time==this.state.question[i].time){
        obj.currentQuestion = i;  //add stuff to it
      }
    }
    this.setState(obj);  //set your final state here
  }.bind(this),1000)
}
```

Comment: OH, i got a stupid mistake, Thank you so much. You have saved my day. :D